# change order of boxes in mobile screen

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive, materialize

I need to make a responsive layout for large screens like this:

```
⎡                 ⎤[                 (1) s12 m9                 ]
⎢   (2) s12 m3    ⎥⎡                                             ⎤
⎢                 ⎥⎢                 (3) s12 m9                  ⎥
⎣                 ⎦⎣                                             ⎦
```

and in small screens:

```
[  (1) s12 m9  ]
[  (2) s12 m3  ]
[  (3) s12 m9  ]
```

I had tested `offset-` and `push-/pull-` but I hadn't be came successfully!

**Edited:**

with push and pull:

```
⎡                 ⎤[             (1) s12 m9 push-m9             ]
⎢   (2) s12 m3    ⎥
⎢   pull-m9       ⎥
⎣                 ⎦
                  [             (3) s12 m9 push-m9             ]
```

Comment: http://materializecss.com/grid.html push and pull is explained here. Have a look at it.

Comment: @Niraj I had tested offset and push/pull. I display the output in question. can you help me?

Comment: ya sure. give me some i will try to reproduce the same on codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: @Niraj in this: https://jsfiddle.net/kzwffzsb/ I show you 2 view with different order. in first view we have good order in large screens and in second one we have good view in small screens.

Comment: @Niraj Do you see my code?

Comment: Before you worry about the CSS, worry about the HTML, because you have `br` tags all over the place that are not helpful.

Comment: @Niraj this theme used as a page skeleton and columns contains unknown height. I use `<br>` tag to show you my content.

Comment: @mrash i saw your code but was not able to find result using push n pull. The second view was better, i am wondering whether this can be done using hide/show along with push/pull based on screen width. Materialize has some built in classes for hide/show.